# How can I reshape a 3D numpy array to 2D?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to reshape a `120 x 2 x 73` numpy array to `2 x 8760`.

Can you help me?

please refer the picture below

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What have you tried? please provide your code attempt.

Answer (score 1):

You need more than reshape; you need to reorder the axes.

```
[3]: arr = np.ones((120,2,73))

In [5]: barr=arr.transpose(1,0,2).reshape(2,8760)
In [6]: barr.shape
Out[6]: (2, 8760)
```

A different transpose, making (2,73,120) before reshape

```
In [7]: barr=arr.transpose(1,2,0).reshape(2,8760)
In [8]: barr.shape
Out[8]: (2, 8760)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(120*2*73).reshape(120,2,73)

b = a.reshape(2, -1)

print(b.shape) # (2, 8760)
```

Comment: I think he wants to keep the size 2 dimension intact.